# How to add components to GameObjects upon initialization?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use this code

```
GameObject mapOutline = new GameObject();
LineRenderer top = mapOutline.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
LineRenderer right = mapOutline.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
LineRenderer bottom = mapOutline.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
LineRenderer left = mapOutline.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
```

However I cannot add these components at the same time the game object is initialised, I get the error "A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property 'ChooseGameMode.mapOutline'"
So is there a way to create the game object already with these components? I know how I could do this by already having the object exist from the unity editor and add the components there but I would rather create it all in code.

Comment: Where are you using this code? Are you using it outside of a function? If so, that is why you are getting this error. Place it in `Awake` or `Start` of a function and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I believe the error you are describing occurs when you attempt to call methods that are not thread-safe within the field initializer or constructor of a class. To be more specific, the methods you are trying to call do not yet exist when you are attempting to call them. To fix this issue, simply move the method calls you are making to a function. Your code can look something like:

```
public class ChooseGameMode : MonoBehaviour
{
     GameObject mapOutline;
     LineRenderer top, right, bottom, left;

     private void Awake()
     {
          mapOutline = new GameObject();
          top = mapOutline.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
          right = mapOutline.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
          bottom = mapOutline.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
          left = mapOutline.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
     }
}
```

Comment: I understand this but then how do I reference these in a seperate method ? Because then I get this error: "'GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'top' and no accessible extension method 'top" accepting a first argument of the type 'GameObject' could be found"
For example in the code `mapOutline.top.positionCount = 2;`

Comment: Just access it as `top.positionCount`. If you want to access them outside of your scripts make the fields `public`.

Comment: @GeorgeBland Did you get this issue resolved or are you still having trouble?

Comment: @TEEQNE No it seems to return null, I cannot tell if this is a general error or me not knowing how to use LineRenderer. I try to se the number of positions of the line as seen above to two (I think this should make a normal stick) Then I try to set each vertex's position using SetPosition(). Does not work.

Comment: @GeorgeBland What returns null? Accessing the `LineRenderer`? What does your new code look like? Can you update your question with the new code?

Comment: @TEEQNE I fixed it, I was giving it a material that did not exist. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @GeorgeBland Glad, you were able to figure it out! If my post helped your original question, you can mark this as the answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the post. It will close the question and let others know that it has a working answer.